# Best Way To Integrate Server Side Laravel Login VueJS SPA

Tags: laravel, vue.js

How can I authenticate a user with sanctum when the whole login process happens server side? The question I am asking is kind of hard to phrase so I will explain my situation.

I have a Vue SPA for my front end and a Laravel app as a backend api (they run on the same domain). Normally, to authenticate with the laravel api using sanctum, you would send the credentials in a post request, and if the login was successful, you would get the session information returned. However, I want to use steam login for authentication. I already have to whole process on the backend figured out in terms of actually logging in, however I am unsure how to pass the session data back to the SPA.  Currently I have a link on my site that takes the user to the login endpoint on the api, and that endpoint will have them authenticate with steam, so the entire login process is handled on the backend. Now I just need to figure out how to send the session data back to the SPA. I guess it world be similar to using sanctum with socialite.

So far I've tried usisng Sanctums [Mobile Aplication Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#mobile-application-authentication). I did this by having the user log in into the laravel app using steam, then once authenticated, a access token for their account would be created, and they would get redirected back to the Vue apps call back file, with the token as a part of the query string. Then the token would be stored and . This worked, however it presented some security issues.

- The token was passed back in the url, so anyone could screenshot it and use it
- Anyone who obtained the token by some other method could use it.

Here is the code for what I tried: https://gist.github.com/DriedSponge/4e8549486c2bfa33e4c0b21a539bdf85

So in summary, I want the entire login process to take place on the server, but somehow at the same time authenticate the SPA. If you have any ideas on how I can make this work, please let me know. If you have any questions just leave a comment. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey thanks, your strategy gave me an idea of how to manage my oauth login. I'm working with Laravel-React but I'm struggling with the implementation. Did you update your code or left it like the one in your link?